# Bash script for writing ls to a file in another directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to write a script that will go to specific directory, `ls` files in this directory and then write it to a file in another directory. This is what I came up with so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
getDisk1(){
   cd cwiczenia | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
   return
}

getDisk2(){
   cd Pictures | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
   return
}

getDisk1
getDisk2
```

I'm running the script from the folder `/home/kai/`, but `getDisk2` isnt writing any results to its destination. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Change this `cd cwiczenia | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt` to `cd cwiczenia && ls >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt`

Comment: @Jesse_b can you explain the syntax `cd cwiczenia | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt`?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Duh.  I wasn't even paying attention to the pipe.  I just was trying to point out he was writing to a file named cd.

Answer (score 3):

Your commands are nonsense:

```
  cd Pictures | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
```

"Go into the `Pictures` directory.  Pipe the (null) output of the `cd` command into `ls`, which does not take standard input.  Send `ls`' output to a file called `cd`."

What you probably want is something like:

```
( cd Pictures; ls >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt )
```

The reason this is in parens is do that it executes in a subshell, and does not (try to) change the working directory of the underlying script.

Either way, it's a bad idea to parse the output of `ls` in general.  It might be better do do something like:

```
find Pictures/ -maxdepth 1 >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
```

If you don't like seeing the path in which the files lie, it's still better to use `find` to actually get the list of files:

```
find Pictures/ -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 basename >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
```

Comment: It was that, or `if cd Pictures; then ls; fi` (:

Comment: I cannot give any points cause im new :( @DopeGhoti what does this mean find Pictures/ -maxdepth 1 >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt? Should i make it in functions?

Comment: also this one cd cwiczenia | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt works the way it is. Im new so dont judge :)

Comment: Note that `ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt` is directly equivalent to the more usual `ls /home/kai/listaplikow.txt >> cd`

Comment: the one with -maxdepth isnt the best solution cause it gives me :

cwiczenia/something
cwiczenia/somethingelse
...

and i would just need
something
somethingelse

is there better solution?

Comment: this one find Pictures/ -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 basename >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt is showing :
basename: extra operand 'cwiczenia/somefile'
Try 'basename --help' for more information

Answer (score 0):

Change you syntax:

```
cd cwiczenia | ls >> cd /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
```

to

```
cd cwiczenia && ls >> /home/kai/listaplikow.txt
```

Explanation:

- `&&`: ensure that the previous command `cd` is successful before the `ls` command is run.

Comment: Thank U @GeorgeUdosen i cannot +1 to anyone cause im new. Should i make in functions?

Comment: I think you can as the question belongs to you!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen [voting up comes at 15 rep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)

Comment: its true @JeffSchaller

Comment: when i make it with function like in my example it says that cd: Pictures no such file or directory. 

both folders cwiczenia and Pictures are in home/kai/, so when im making first function and im going into cwiczenia folder and then make second function that goes to Pictures folder i should first make cd .. and then go into Pictures? cause i thought that my script is always in the folder that im executing it